Kernel of a Mikhlin multiplier is a Calderón–Zygmund kernel (reference request)
Consider any function (convolution kernel) $K(x):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$. Suppose the Fourier transform of $K(x)$, denoted by $\hat{K}(\xi):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the standard Mikhlin multiplier condition,
\begin{equation*}
\left|\nabla^n \hat{K}(\xi)\right|\le C |\xi|^{-n},
\end{equation*}
for all $n=0,\dots,\frac{d}{2}+1$, and some $C>0$. Then $K(x)$ is also a Calderón–Zymund kernel. That is
\begin{gather*}
\left|K(x)\right|\le C'|x|^{-d}, \\
\left|\nabla K(x)\right|\le C' |x|^{-d-1},
\end{gather*}
for some $C'>0$.
My question is a reference for this result, including also the relationship between $C$ and $C'$ (presumably $C'\le AC$ for some $A>0$).
EDIT: as kindly mentioned by Giorgio Metafune, the result is true if we replace $\frac{d}{2}+1$ by $d+2$, see for example the proof in Theorem 8.2, Classical and multilinear harmonic analysis. Vol. I, by Camil Muscalu and Wilhelm Schlag.

I do not know if this is true as stated.  I know that if this is almost true if $n$ runs from 0 to d+2, in the sense that one can approximate with Calderon-Zygmund operators with uniform bounds. However, it is true that Mikhlin holds under the hypotesis up to the integer part od $d/2 +1$, but one needs other argumnets.
